# Find the number of numbers with 5 digits that don't have the sequence 17 within them

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

This is simillar to another question that was asked on here but with 4 digits instead, I have already seen that question and used the same method, but for some reason I am still getting this question wrong.

Here is my thinking

XXXXX 5 spots

$9*10^4$ total numbers

17XXX

X17XX

XX17X

XXX17

$(10^3+9*10^2+9^2*10+9^3)$ = total number of numbers with 17 in them.

But since we counted some numbers twice

$(10^3+9*10^2+9^2*10+9^3 - 29)$

$9*10^4 - (10^3+9*10^2+9^2*10+9^3 - 29) = 86590$ using calculator

It says my answer is wrong, but I can't figure out what I have failed to take into account.

Comment: Why the $9^3$ term in the "total number of numbers with 17 in them"?

Comment: You are ignoring all numbers with zero in the second or third place. Your $9^2\cdot 10$ and $9^3$ should both be $9\cdot 10^2$.

Comment: @TonyK Oh right, its only necessary for the first digit to not be 0, that's kind of silly, I don't know why my brain went to the assumption that all digits before had to not be 0.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As TonyK pointed out in the comments, you overlooked the fact that while the leading digit cannot be equal to zero, the remaining digits can be equal to zero.

Let $A_i$, $1 \leq i \leq 4$, be the set of five-digit positive integers in which the sequence $17$ appears beginning in the $i$th position.

Since there are $9 \cdot 10^4$ positive integers with five digits, the number of five-digit positive integers in which the sequence $17$ does not appear is
$$9 \cdot 10^4 - |A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4|$$
By the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle,
\begin{align*}
|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4| & = \sum_{i = 1}^{4} |A_i| - \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq 4} |A_i \cap A_j|\\
& \qquad + \sum_{1 \leq i < j < k \leq 4} |A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k| - |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4\\
& = |A_1| + |A_2| + |A_3| + |A_4|\\
& \quad - |A_1 \cap A_2| - |A_1 \cap A_3| - |A_1 \cap A_4| - |A_2 \cap A_3| - |A_2 \cap A_4| - |A_3 \cap A_4|\\
& \qquad + |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3| + |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4| + |A_1 \cap A_3 \cap A_4| + |A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4|\\
& \quad\qquad - |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4|
\end{align*}

$|A_1|$:  Since the sequence $17$ appears in the first two positions, there are $10$ choices for each of the remaining digits.  Hence, $|A_1| = 10^3$.

$|A_2|$:  Since the sequence $17$ appears in the second and third positions, there are nine choices for the leading digit and $10$ choices for each of the remaining digits.  Hence, $|A_2| = 9 \cdot 10^2$.

By symmetry, $|A_2| = |A_3| = |A_4|$.

$|A_1 \cap A_2|$:  This means that the sequence $17$ appears in both the first two positions and the second and third positions, which is impossible since the second digit would have to be both $1$ and $7$.  Hence, $|A_1 \cap A_2| = 0$.

By symmetry, $|A_1 \cap A_2| = |A_2 \cap A_3| = |A_3 \cap A_4|$.

$|A_1 \cap A_3|$:  This means that the sequence $17$ appears in both the first and second positions and third and fourth positions.  There are $10$ choices for the fifth position.  Hence, $|A_1 \cap A_3| = 10$.

By symmetry, $|A_1 \cap A_3| = |A_1 \cap A_4|$.

$|A_2 \cap A_4|$:  This means that the sequence $17$ appears in both the second and third positions and in the fourth and fifth positions.  There are $9$ choices for the leading digit.  Hence, $|A_2 \cap A_4| = 9$.

Since there cannot be more than two appearances of the sequence $17$ in a five-digit positive integer, each of the remaining terms is equal to zero.

Hence,
$$|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4| = 10^3 + 3 \cdot 9 \cdot 10^2 - 2 \cdot 10 - 9$$
Therefore, the number of five-digit positive integers that do not contain the sequence $17$ is
$$9 \cdot 10^4 - 10^3 - 3 \cdot 9 \cdot 10^2 + 2 \cdot 10 + 9 = 86,329$$

Comment: Taussing: Imagine the O:P. just have asked about the case $17cde$ (the case i called $1)$. What is the answer give by your  Inclusion-Exclusion Principle? It is not $90000-980?. I thing my answer, deleted now, is not wrong as you believed.

Comment: @Piquito  There are $1000$ five-digit positive integers of the form $17cde$, of which there are $980$ numbers in which the sequence $17$ appears exactly once since there are $10$ numbers of the form $1717e$ and ten numbers of the form $17c17$.  In each of your four cases, you subtracted the number of five-digit positive integers in which the sequence $17$ appears exactly once.  Therefore, when you subtracted the amounts you found from the $90,000$ five-digit positive integers, you missed the $29$ five-digit numbers in which the sequence $17$ appears twice (the other $9$ have the form $a1717$).

Comment: Taussig:  Thanks you for your reply. However the case $a1717$ is not anymore of the form $17abc$ so it is not of of the case $1)$ but of the case $2)$. Best regards.